# How to tell latex what i write should stay as it is, and not as a mathematical expression

Tags: tables

I'm trying to write my thesis on Latex and I don't have much experience with it. I try to put an information about some arrays i used as a table one like looks like this:
column names:

> FileName, Strain, Replicate

for this i use this code:

```
\begin{tabular}
US45102998_251897210500_S01_GE1_107_Sep09_1_3.txt & RAL765 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}
```

what LaTeX thinks it is:
`US45102998251897210573S01GE1107Sep0911.txt` It creates this line where the numbers after underscore are subscripts of the former text. I used  \textdollar{} and it didn't work for me . I used `\verb{}`, and it worked (it didnt turn the text into a mathematical expression), but now I see "}" sign right after the text and it doesn't break the line.

the full code is:

```
\begin{center}
\tablehead{Array Information}
\toprule
\tableheadline {File Name} & \tableheadline{Strain} & \tableheadline{Replicate} \\ \midrule 
\hline}
\tabletail{\multicolumn{4}{r} {Continued on next page...} \\}
\tablecaption{Array information}
\xentrystretch{0}
\begin{tabular}{llll{5 cm}}
\label{xtab: arrayinformation}
```

And at the end it is:

```
\hline
\end{xtabular}
\end{center}
```

Any suggestions? Note: i'm not so familiar with LaTeX lingo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s rather unfortunate that LaTeX by default thinks that `_` only belongs in math mode. If you want to use it in text mode, you need to use `\_` instead.

The [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-underscore) gives more details about the usage of underscores in LaTeX.

Comment: wow thanks that actually worked! i have 7 underscores in a line for a table of 84 lines... but still better than going crazy on neverending lines, subscripted texts...

Comment: You can also use the underscore package (put `\use{underscore}` in the preamble of your document), and it will then let you use bare underscores in text mode, while still treating them as subscript indicators in math mode.